# Javascript on submit button

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have some question. I have the html form with one hidden input element. And I have an array in my javascript code. I want to catch pressing submit button event (by using jquery) and push the array data in the hidden input.

The question is - what happens first: form date will flow to .php script or javascript's array will be pushed into hidden input and afterwords .php script will be called? And why it is so?

TIA!

**upd (code sample):**

```
...
// process $_POST['domains']
...

<form action="registration?id=reg" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="reg_form">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" id="domains" name="domains[]" value=""/>
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Register"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var domainlist = [];

    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (name) {
        var ind = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i].name == name) {
                ind = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ind;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        ...
    });

    function checkDomain() {
        ...
            req = $.ajax({
                type:           'post',
                cache:          false,
                url:            'ajax.php',
                data:           ...,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#domain_list_wrap').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', function () {
                        var dmnName = $(this).attr('name');
                        domainlist.push({name: dmnName, cost: domainsArr[dmnName.split('.')[1]]});
                        ...
                    });
                    $('#domain_cart').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', function () {
                        domainlist.splice(domainlist.indexOf($(this).attr('name')), 1);
                        ...
                    });
                }
            });
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you code it such that the hidden field is populated first, the hidden field will be populated first.

Comment: it is better if you add some code to your question. for passing array values from the same HTML page you do not need PHP to process it. create a JavaScript function and call it when the form is submitted. make sure the the function returns FALSE to stop the page from completing the submisson to the action page (in the HTML form). Hope this will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JavaScript `submit` event is fired when the form is submitted, but before the request is made to the server (as JavaScript runs on the client side this makes perfect sense). Therefore, the way you have imagined it working should be fine, and you can bind to the form submit event using jQuery as follows:

```
$("#yourForm").submit(function() {
    //Submit event handler will run on form submit
});
```

The `submit` event handler can also be used to cancel form submission (for example, if some validation fails) by returning false. It wouldn't really work if the data was sent to the server first!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your body

```
<form id="frm" method="post" action="/">
    <input type="hidden" id="txtHidden" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And this in your head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = [ "hello", "there", "world" ];

    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#btnSubmit").click( function(event) {
                   var str = arr.join(",");
                   $("#txtHidden").val(str);
                   // make sure the value is in the field
                   alert($("#txtHidden").val());
            });
    });

</script>
```

When you click on btnSubmit, the array will be joined with commas, you'll see the alert, then the form will be submitted.

Comment: So, .click event fires before .submit event?

Comment: Yes! Otherwise you wouldn't have seen the alert :-)